# how to load an HTML file inside a div in the view in zend-framework3?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an email marketing tool and need to load an HTML template inside a DIV in the view. I'm using zend-framework3.
I tried to use the .load () function, but it is giving error. Can anybody help me??

I'm using something like this:

```
$('#carregaTemplate').click(function(){

    var qtdProdutos = $('#qtdProdutos').val();

    $(function(){
        if( qtdProdutos == 1 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/sem_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 2 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/dois_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 3 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/tres_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 4 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/quatro_produtos.html');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: _Giving an Error_ Would you mind terribly, telling us ___what error it is giving you___ old chap

Comment: _I'm using something like this:_ somthing like that? If you show us pseudo code, you are just going to get pseudo answers

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: No need to use `$(function()` inside a click event handler. Won't cause errors but is just redundant

Comment: Sorry buddy, I'm new here in the stack and I'm going to rephrase ... I'm using exactly the above function and I get the error 500 @RiggsFolly

Comment: 500 errors are Server end errors. Normally a catastrophic PHP error.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. I was able to reach the resolution by using the example contained here https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Regex_Route_Type.html

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I solved the problem as follows:

I created a Regex-type route. This type of route allows you to work with static pages. See example here: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Regex_Route_Type.html

In the controller, I created the following responsible function for rendering the pages:

public function docAction() {

```
    $pageTemplate = 'email-marketing/template/doc' . $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 'documentation.phtml');

    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/../../view/' . $pageTemplate . '.phtml';        
    if (!file_exists($filePath) || !is_readable($filePath)) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }

    $viewModel = new ViewModel([
        'page'=>$pageTemplate
    ]);
    $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layoutVazio');
    $viewModel->setTemplate($pageTemplate);

    return $viewModel;
}
```

The function that loads the page inside a DIV, in my case, looks like this:

function loadTemplate() {

```
    var qtdProdutos = $('#qtdProdutos').val();

    if( qtdProdutos == 1 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'pagina']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 2 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'dois_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 3 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'tres_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 4 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'quatro_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }

}
```